# Mapeamento de entidade com .Net Core 2

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

tenho as seguintes entidades:

```
 public class Transacao : IEntity
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; private set; }

        public int LojaId { get; set; }
        public virtual Loja Loja { get; set; }

        public int AdquirenteId { get; set; }
        public virtual Adquirente Adquirente { get; set; }

        public DateTime Data { get; set; }
        public Guid Numero { get; set; }
        public int NumeroPedido { get; set; }
        public Decimal Valor { get; set; }
    }

public class Adquirente : IEntity
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; private set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        [Display(Name = "Nome")]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        public int AdquirenteId { get; set; }

        public List<LojaAdquirente> LojaAdquirentes { get; set; }
    }

public class Loja : IEntity
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; private set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(18)]
        [Display(Name = "CNPJ")]
        public string CNPJ { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        [Display(Name = "Nome")]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        [Display(Name = "Endereço")]
        public string Endereco { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Possui Antifraude Habilitado")]
        public bool IsAntiFraudeEnabled { get; set; }

        public Guid Token { get; set; }

        public int LojaId { get; set; }

        public List<LojaAdquirente> LojaAdquirentes { get; set; }
    }
```

Quando vou recuperar os registros do banco de dados (_context.Transacao.Where(x => x.Loja.Token.Equals(tokenLoja)); as entidades Loja e Adquirente estão vindo nulo. O que eu preciso fazer pra carregar essas entidades junto com a entidade pai?

Comment: Se pode usar o Include (que é o carregamento adiantado), se pode utilizar o pacote de LazyLoad para o carregamento preguiçoso ou até a interface ILazyLoader ... De rapida ação utilize o Include. `_context.Transacao.Include(i=>i.LojaAdquirentes).Where(x => x.Loja.Token.Equals(tokenLoja))`

Comment: Obrigado Virgílio! Funcionou! :)